# When we inject IWorkContext in WebStoreContext its gives error

Tags: nopcommerce

I am trying to inject  `IWorkContext` in `WebStoreContext` or `StoreService`.

but when we run the project it give's errors.

Error on `ContainerManager.cs(line no 113)`

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Autofac.dll
```

example

```
private readonly IWorkContext _workContext = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
```

Or

```
private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;

public ctor(IWorkContext workContex)
{
    this._workContex = workContext;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular references are not allowed. WorkContext already depends on IStoreContext. You cannot make StoreContext already depends on IWorkContext.

Comment: hello and.maz thanks for reply..can you give me idea how to get current customer id in WebStoreContext.cs page?

Comment: @and.maz Can you Guide How to get current Customer in WebStoreContext in Nop.framewrk ... please guide need help...

Comment: @and.maz Please Suggest me idea of how to get current customer in WebStoreContext in Nop.framework.