# Get Current Customer in nopcommerce3.3

Tags: nopcommerce

I am working in a nopCommerce 3.3 project which is in mvc framework.I wanted to get current customer id in WebStoreContext page. How can i get current customer in nopCommerce 3.3?

Regards,
Jatin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have learnt from your other question,  [When we inject IWorkContext in WebStoreContext its gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566962/when-we-inject-iworkcontext-in-webstorecontext-its-gives-error), you cannot reference the IWorkContext from the StoreContext because it causes circular references (you can accept the answer). Getting an instance of the IAuthenticationService could be of use, but has the same circular reference problem.

Assuming that you don't mind modifying the core classes, you should think about an alternative approach like one of these:

- Use an alternate method to get the current user from the `StoreContext`: You cannot use the `IWorkContext`, `IAuthenticationService` and it is too early to get the Forms.Identity because first call comes from Application_BeginRequest. But you can get the user from the cookies, for instance, you can get the customer GUID from the Nop.customer cookie. You cannot use `CustomerSettings` or `ICustomerService` either, so you will need to query the customer repository directly to get the customer details.
- But my favorite is this one. Add a new filter to the `BasePublicController`, you can check the `WwwRequirement` filter as reference. Add any check you need there and redirect the consumer to the proper shop and route at will.

Answer (score 0):

```
WorkContext.CurrentCustomer.Id
```

Comment: Can you Guide How to get current Customer in WebStoreContext in Nop.framewrk ... please guide need help...

Comment: Why would you want to get it inside WebStoreContext? WorkContext should be the correct class to use.

Comment: i want to load store by customer id so i want to customer id in WebStoreContext.

Comment: what do you mean by "load store by customer id"? Can you explain your scenario?

Comment: see nopcommerce store display by URL right? and now i want to store display by current customer wise... so store display from WebStoreContext so i want to current customer in WebStoreContext page.. please guide need help

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your sentence: "see nopcommerce store display by URL right? and now i want to store display by current customer wise...". Can you please explain again? Anyway, WorkContext.CurrentCustomer always get the currently logged in user, so I don't know why you must do it in StoreContext.

Comment: Because store display from StoreContext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56804/discussion-between-jatin-gadhiya-and-wooncherk).